# Error: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i got Error: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' when trying to execute the process..I'm still new to php so i would like to know what is the problem with my coding.

this is the coding first.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");


$q = mysql_query("SELECT bachok_qtt FROM bachok WHERE bachok_type = 'pants' ");
if(is_resource($q) and mysql_num_rows($q)>0)
{
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    $r["bachok_qtt"];
}

$w = mysql_query("SELECT bachok_qtt FROM bachok WHERE bachok_type = 'clothes' ");
if(is_resource($w) and mysql_num_rows($w)>0)
{
    $s = mysql_fetch_array($w);
    $s["bachok_qtt"];
}       

$e = mysql_query("SELECT stock_qtt FROM stock WHERE stock_type = 'pants' ");
if(is_resource($e) and mysql_num_rows($e)>0)
{
    $a = mysql_fetch_array($e);
    $a["stock_qtt"];
}    

$t = mysql_query("SELECT stock_qtt FROM stock WHERE stock_type = 'clothes' ");
if(is_resource($t) and mysql_num_rows($t)>0)
{
    $b = mysql_fetch_array($t);
    $b["stock_qtt"];
}    


if ($r < $a)
{
    if($s < $b)
    {
        $sql1 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - $r  WHERE stock_type = 'pants' ";
        $sql2 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - $s  WHERE stock_type = 'clothes' ";

        $result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());

        if($result1)
        {
            if($result2)
            {
            echo "Successful";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<a href='admin2.php'>Back to main page</a>";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Not enough stock";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='admin2.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}




?>
```

So, why does it throw unknown column array when executed..Hav I used MySQL_fetch_array() correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can look at `$r["bachok_qtt"];` 
perhaps you wanted to say something like `$r = $r["bachok_qtt"];`

Comment: thanks all but i have solve it by doing like u said..mr Ashwini has corrected me before..thanks..^^

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here..

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - $r  WHERE stock_type = 'pants' ";
$sql2 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - $s  WHERE stock_type = 'clothes' ";
```

Both `$r` and `$s` are array.

I think you are trying to do this..

```
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$r = $r["bachok_qtt"];
```

Comment: it works.. thanks sir..so it means that when i type $r = $r["bachok_qtt"]; so the variable would be int?

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal not quite. The data type in MySQL is not converted in PHP. Don't forget that PHP is a weakly-typed language...

Comment: @BenM. then he must convert the variable to `int`.

Comment: Again, not necessarily.

Comment: then..?? what if the variable contains string?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you define `$r` as an array, and then try to use it in a string. Looking over your code, I actually suspect that you wish to assign the value of `$r["bachok_qtt"]` to a variable, and then use it inside your query.

For example the following code doesn't do anything:

```
$r["bachok_qtt"];
```

You should update your code as follows:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT bachok_qtt FROM bachok WHERE bachok_type = 'pants' ");
if(is_resource($q) and mysql_num_rows($q)>0)
{
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    $bachok_qtt = $r["bachok_qtt"];
}

$w = mysql_query("SELECT bachok_qtt FROM bachok WHERE bachok_type = 'clothes' ");
if(is_resource($w) and mysql_num_rows($w)>0)
{
    $s = mysql_fetch_array($w);
    $bachok2 = $s["bachok_qtt"];
}
```

And then your SQL as follows:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - $bachok_qtt  WHERE stock_type = 'pants' ";
$sql2 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - $bachok2  WHERE stock_type = 'clothes' ";
```

You should also be advised that the `mysql_*` family of functions are now in the process of deprecation, and will be invalid shortly. Instead of using them in new code, you should look into the use of [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Not only do they bring the benefits of longevity to the table, but they also remove some of the security risks of using `mysql_*`.

Comment: thanks a lot mr BenM.. i am a beginner in php and trying to learn this by myself actually..

Answer (score 0):

here you go i  fixed your erros . try this

```
 <?php
 include("dbconnect.php");


 $q = mysql_query("SELECT bachok_qtt FROM bachok WHERE bachok_type = 'pants' ");
 if(is_resource($q) and mysql_num_rows($q)>0)
 {
  $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

  }

 $w = mysql_query("SELECT bachok_qtt FROM bachok WHERE bachok_type = 'clothes' ");
 if(is_resource($w) and mysql_num_rows($w)>0)
 {
  $s = mysql_fetch_array($w);

 }       

 $e = mysql_query("SELECT stock_qtt FROM stock WHERE stock_type = 'pants' ");
 if(is_resource($e) and mysql_num_rows($e)>0)
 {
  $a = mysql_fetch_array($e);

 }    

 $t = mysql_query("SELECT stock_qtt FROM stock WHERE stock_type = 'clothes' ");
 if(is_resource($t) and mysql_num_rows($t)>0)
 {
 $b = mysql_fetch_array($t);

 }    


 if ($r["bachok_qtt"] < $a["stock_qtt"])
 {
 if($s["bachok_qtt"] < $b["stock_qtt"])
 {
    $sql1 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - '".$r["bachok_qtt"]."'  WHERE stock_type = 'pants' ";
    $sql2 = "UPDATE stock SET stock_qtt = stock_qtt - '".$s["bachok_qtt"]."'  WHERE stock_type = 'clothes' ";

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());

    if($result1)
    {
        if($result2)
        {
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href='admin2.php'>Back to main page</a>";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Not enough stock";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<a href='admin2.php'>Back to main page</a>";
 }

  ?>
```